# How to calibrate monitor colors to use 3D glasses?

Tags: video, display, colors, calibration, 3d-vision

I have a pair of red/cyan 3D glasses and when I use them to view youtube's 3D videos or anaglyph images they dont seem to work properly. The two images are not filtered properly by each colored lens.
So I guess the problem is my monitor not showing the exact colors needed for my glasses to work.

Is there any way to customize/calibrate the monitor's colors for a specific pair of 3D glasses?

PS: I also have green/magenta and amber/blue glasses, but the same problem happens.

Comment: cool question buddy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most monitor calibration tools - the ones that come with devices that read the screen - are quite expensive and probably overkill for what you want.

There are guides out there - [this one](http://www.ephotozine.com/article/Monitor-calibration--equipment-instructions-4611) for example, and I know that you can get [test cards](http://reeddesign.co.uk/testcard.htm) to calibrate the brightness and contrast. You could try these first.

Also bear in mind that the free glasses that get given out won't be that accurate anyway.

Another thing to consider is that if you're slightly red/green colour blind or have one eye significantly more dominant than the other you might not see the 3D effect any way.

If you go to see a 3D movie can you see that OK? I know that uses polarised light and lenses but would rule out the dominant eye issue.

Comment: I tried tunning the colors using a feature that my video card has, but I couldn't manage to set it in a way that the two images in the anaglyph are filtered completely by each lens. So I guess these paperboard glasses are not good enough. I wonder if those plastic frame glasses will do any better.

Answer (score 2):

If you have the time (judging since you're trying to watch Youtube in 3D, very probably), you can do manual calibration.
Start by drawing a red (#FF000) square in your favorite image editor surrounded by white, and play with your monitor settings until the red square disappears. Do the same with blue (#0000FF).
That may be the easiest way, if not the fastest.

Comment: Color code for Red is ff0000... not ff000...